Cannot locate pyodbc module in Gitlab Pipeline
While running the python code in Gitlab pipeline, the 'pyodbc' module is getting installed however while running the 'import pyodbc' its throwing the error 'ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
I have done the RnD and found that unixodbc package is required for this.
I am looking for some solution on how to install unixodbc package through gitlab pipeline.
(I am using the python image from nexus repository)
Tried to run 'sudo apt-get install unixodbc' cmd but its giving 'sudo command not found'
